# How to say "affluenza" in Russian?

Tags: перевод

How do I say "affluenza" in Russian? 
I am specifically referring to the negative connotation of a condition in which a person or some people pursue material possessions simply to have them. For example, "his parents suffer from affluenza; they waste their monthly savings buying *fancy new* products that they store indefinitely in their garage." I could not find any translations of the word online.

Comment: Please provide some context. What exactly does this phrase means in English? Provide an evidence of some initial research.

Comment: "Его родители - транжиры, тратят всю зарплату на шмотки"

Comment: Well affluenza is quite new even for English language. I think there is no direct translation. Транжира is just a person that spends a lot of money, but not "stores products indefinitely in their garage". A person that "stores products indefinitely" is скопидом, but he is far from being a person that spends a lot of money.

Comment: As far as I understand, affluenza means "various negative psychological effects of wealth". In this sense, I'd probably use "самодурство" - it means "doing stupid things, thinking you're powerful enough to do whatever you want". It is a bit less specific, though, as it only implies power (real or assumed), not necessarily wealth.

Answer (score 3):

*Вещизм*, *безудержное потребление* can be used to describe it. Translators also use general terms : *перепотребление*, *потребительство* and **консьюмеризм**, a loan word, which is most often used nowadays. *Ониомания* (*шопоголизм*, *шопинголизм*) is a medical term, a sort of addiction.

> Он страдает от вещизма.( страдает шопоманией)
>
> Эта неконтролируемая тяга что-либо приобретать, невзирая на необходимость и последствия, называется ониоманией, шопоголизмом или просто вещизмом.

From National corpus.

> Нездоровый вещизм как один из признаков современного общества потребления ежегодно достигает своего апогея в канун рождественских и новогодних праздников.
>
> По-моему, это мудро: в классе должны царить дисциплина и равенство детей перед знаниями, а не вещизм и похвальба возможностями родителей
>
> Безудержное потребление стало новой мировой религией. Миллионы людей в разных странах живут ради того, чтобы покупать все больше товаров. Аппетиты потребителей растут, с каждым годом становясь изощрённее.

Comment: а почему через "а"? Шопоголизм же ж

Comment: Вещизм is a good translation.

Comment: Could you please add some example sentences using those words? Would the sentence "Он страдает из-за его проклятый вещизм" work?

Comment: @Val Z. Он страдает из-за своей безудержной шопомании. (шоппинг + мания)

Comment: Страдает не "из‐за ", а "от" или чем.

Comment: Он страдает от *своего проклятого вещизма*

Comment: You can't really use any of these in a conversation. It's Soviet press stamps. Шопомания the only usable word of this bunch.

Comment: А за "потреблядство" здесь забанят? :-O

Comment: @bipll, видела эти эпатажные экзерсисы.

Answer (score 1):

There is a term *покупательский зуд* (literally, "the buyer's itch"), "an urge to buy things just for the sake of buying".

Unfortunately, it's not attested in the corpus yet, however, brief googling shows it's been used in print for some time:

> - Удивительно, ты начинаешь испытывать покупательский зуд именно тогда, когда в театре ломается машина!
> - В одном из недавних номеров «Нью-Йорк таймс» научный обозреватель Николас Бакалар называет «покупательский зуд», охвативший жителей развитых стран на рубеже тысячелетий, настоящим психическим заболеванием.
> - Эйфория, азарт, и даже гордость охватывали каждого покупателя, попавшего на территорию внезапного рая, вызывающего неудержимый покупательский зуд.

The earliest entry in Google Books is from 2003.

Answer (score -1):

```
Его родители - транжиры, спускают всю зарплату на шмотки и барахло
```

The profound difference here is that `транжира` is not newspeak like `affluenza` is but a good old literary word.

Comment: An even greater difference is that "affluenza" and "транжира" (or let's say "транжирство") have  different meanings.

Comment: @Abakan you seem to imply there exist two words in any languages with exact the same meaning.

Comment: You seem to think that two words with marginally overlapping meanings can be used as translations for each other.

Comment: @Abakan they definitely can, when those meanings overlap. That's the only thing that matters.